# Можно вызвать метод возвращающий значение в child thread?

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность, task

Я хочу вызвать метод возвращающий значение во время выполнения дочернего потока(child thread). Возможно это сделать ?
Весь код прогресс бара взят [из этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1088121/178835). Как мне вызвать методы Resources.Load ("Texture/Rock (Moss)"); и AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (tempTex2D); в дочернем потоке?

Мой метод в дочернем потоке :

```
async private static void DumbTaskExample (int subTaskCount, int sleepTime, SynchronizationContext context, CancellationToken token) {
    Debug.Log ($"Task started at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    for (int i = 0; i < subTaskCount; i++) {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();
        Thread.Sleep (sleepTime);
        string path = "none";
        Texture2D tempTex2D;
        tempTex2D = await Task.Run (() => {
            return Resources.Load<Texture2D> ("Texture/Rock (Moss)");
        });
        path = await Task.Run (() => { return AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (tempTex2D); });
        Debug.Log ("path=" + path);
        context.Post (_ => GetCustomWindow (false).Progress = (float) i / subTaskCount, null);
    }
    Debug.Log ($"Task done at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    context.Post (_ => GetCustomWindow (true).OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled (), null);
}
```

Ошибка:

```
UnityException: somefunction  can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
```

Comment: Где вызвать? Куда возвращающий и откуда?

Comment: @V.March Вызывается в коде. Возвращает в код из кода. Все понятно?

Comment: @V.March более подробно с чем я столкнул , когда пробовал это сделать . Описал здесь : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060364/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be

Comment: @V.March я дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Ver Nick says Reinstate Monica я дополнил вопрос

Comment: @IvanTriumphov а у Вас не Unity случайно?

Comment: @V.March  Unity у меня

Comment: @V.March  Там что по другому работает?

Comment: @V.March Мне причём желательно это сделать не изменяя метод , дописывая out int val в метод , или какие другие изменения модифицирующие метод. Так как есть методы которые нельзя будет поменять . Например AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[i]); . Его я не смогу модифицировать

Comment: @IvanTriumphov  Смотрели эту переписку? https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise/issues/12

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102368/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-v-march).

Comment: Спасибо, но нет.  Может Вам поможет: http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/the-dispatcher-pattern/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

класс [Dispatcher](http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/the-dispatcher-pattern/) помог решить проблему(я теперь могу в дочернем потоке вызвать метод в основном потоке), спасибо @V.March:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
// using System.Windows.Threading;
using System;
using System.Windows;
public interface IDispatcher
{
    void Invoke(Action fn);
}
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    public List<Action> pending = new List<Action>();
    private static Dispatcher instance;
    public void Invoke(Action fn)
    {
        lock (pending)
        {
            pending.Add(fn);
        }
    }
    public void InvokePending()
    {
        lock (pending)
        {
            foreach (var action in pending)
            {
                action();
            }
            pending.Clear();
        }
    }
    public static Dispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                // Instance singleton on first use.
                instance = new Dispatcher();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

А делаю это так, в дочернем потоке если надо выполнить метод из основного потока , можно написать :

```
        Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke(() =>
           {
               path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[index]);
               Debug.Log("Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke.path=" + path);
           }
        );
```

и подождать пока прийдёт ответ ..например с помощью `while`

Пример:

```
_thread = new Thread(() => _worker.Work("", null));
_thread.Start();
```

Класс для потока :

```
internal class Worker
{
    public static bool _cancelled = false;
    public List<Terrain> lstTerrain = null;
    public List<string> listStringUrlTexture = null;
    public List<int> idtexture = null;
    public List<mapObject> myList = null;
    public int count_list_index = -3;
    public Texture2D[] GamObjArrayTexture = null;
    public Terrain[] TerrainList = new Terrain[0];
    public float brushsize = 3;
    public static void Cancel()
    {
        _cancelled = true;
    }
    public event Action<int> ProcessChanged;
    public event Action<bool> WorkCompleted;
    public event Action<string> WorkLog;
    public void Work(string tempStringTextFieldURLjsonfile = "", List<Terrain> templstTerrain = null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (_cancelled)
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(50);
            Debug.Log("i=" + i);
            // int val = marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.somefunction(i);
            // Debug.Log("val=" + val);
            string path = "None";
            //Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
            Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke(
                () =>
                {
                    path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(GamObjArrayTexture[1]);
                    Debug.Log("Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke.path=" + path);
                }
            );
            while (path == "None")
            {
                marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(0);
                marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(25);
                marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(50);
                marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(100);
            }
            //Thread.CurrentThread.Start();

            Debug.Log("ENDpath=" + path);
            marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_ProcessChanged(i);

        }
        marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.worker_WorkCompleted(_cancelled);
    }
}
```

Не забудьте поставить:

```
Dispatcher.Instance.InvokePending();
```

в `Update()` или `OnGUI()`. Иначе из-за `while(){}` процесс некогда не завершиться.