# Как подождать пока выполнится поток?

Tags: c#, unity3d, многопоточность, unity3d-editor

У меня есть класс Dispatcher :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
// using System.Windows.Threading;
using System;
using System.Windows;
public interface IDispatcher
{
    void Invoke(Action fn);
}
public class Dispatcher : IDispatcher
{
    public List<Action> pending = new List<Action>();
    private static Dispatcher instance;
    public void Invoke(Action fn)
    {
        lock (pending)
        {
            pending.Add(fn);
        }
    }
    public void InvokePending()
    {
        lock (pending)
        {
            foreach (var action in pending)
            {
                action();
            }
            pending.Clear();
        }
    }
    public static Dispatcher Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                // Instance singleton on first use.
                instance = new Dispatcher();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Я хочу дождаться завершения метода, который я запускаю с помощью Dispatcher :

```
Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke(() =>
{
    tempСoordinatesListVector3 = randomPointsInPolygon(brushsize, tempСoordinatesListVector3);
    foreach (var coordinat in tempСoordinatesListVector3)
    {
        Debug.Log("randomPointsInPolygon" + coordinat);
    }
    processBool = true;
});
```

Пока я жду так :

```
Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke(() =>
{
    tempСoordinatesListVector3 = randomPointsInPolygon(brushsize, tempСoordinatesListVector3);
    foreach (var coordinat in tempСoordinatesListVector3)
    {
        Debug.Log("randomPointsInPolygon" + coordinat);
    }
    processBool = true;
});


while (processBool == false)
{
    if (processBool == false) { processBool = processProgressBar(); } else { processBool = true; }
    Debug.Log("111.3");
}
processBool = false;
Debug.Log("111.3");
```

Но это костыль, который даже не всегда работает. От переменной processBool зависит будет ли дальше выполнятся приложение.
Как переписать класс Dispatcher, чтобы он возвращал IAsyncResult и ждал BackgroundDispatcher.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104915/discussion-on-question-by-ivan-triumphov-----).

Comment: Сделал более общий faq вопрос-ответ, чтобы можно было на него ссылаться в общих случаях: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1088120/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-unity/1088121#1088121

Comment: @RiotBr3aker спасибо сегодня буду смотреть ваш пример )))

Answer (score 0):

Я не работал в юнити, но вот вам простой пример

```
        //получаем контекст синхронизации
        var uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //что-то делаем в дочернем потоке...
            //например находим файлы картинок и находим наибольший по размеру файл
            string pictures = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
            var folder = new DirectoryInfo(pictures);
            FileInfo[] allFiles = folder.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            FileInfo largest = allFiles.OrderByDescending(f => f.Length).FirstOrDefault();

            //когда нашли наибольший, надо вывести в основной поток
            //данные по размеру
            //используем для этого контекст синхронизации
            uiContext.Post(_ =>
            { 

                long sizeMB = largest.Length / (1024 * 1024);
                //здесь в текстбокс окна программы выводим размер файла
                outputTextBox.Text = $"Largest file ({sizeMB}MB) is {largest.FullName}";
            }, null);
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо с утра попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Ну, успехов....

Comment: я остался не понят мне надо в дочернем потоке , выполнить метод который в дочернем потоке не выполняется. Вот вопрос, который я задавал раньше https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1060377/178835 (в вопросе выполниться может код, но встречаются методы которые вываливают ошибку ). Ошибка следующая :can only be called from the main thread.

Comment: Для этого я и написал Dispatcher , который взял тут http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/the-dispatcher-pattern/

Comment: `... в дочернем потоке , выполнить метод который в дочернем потоке не выполняется...`, т.е. из главного потока порождаете дочерний, а из дочернего вызываете метод основного потока? Я вас правильно понял? Если, да, то это циклическая зависимость потоков между собой и это очень  очень плохая затея, циклических зависимостей быть не должно. В главном потоке вы должны создавать дочерний, в нем производить какие-то вычисления, возвращать или не возвр. результат в главный и дальше в главном что-то делать с этим результатом.

Comment: вызываются и методы основного потока , но не только иногда вызываются методы которые есть в библиотеках Unity , они тоже выполняются только благодаря диспечеру...... Вообще в противном случае , я не знаю что делать с прогресс баром .....у меня метод отрисовки полигона деревьев, вызывает минимум пять  методов ещё)

Comment: Знаете, когда рыболовная леска запутывается она зовется "бородой". Вот и у вас, похоже, в игре не архитектура, а борода из вызывающих друг друга потоков и методов. Это чертов ад называется. Такое приложение нормально отладить не получается,  найти и исправить ошибку невозможно. Прежде всего следует отделить слой визуального интерфейса от слоя логики игры. Главный поток должен порождать дочерние, получать результат и если надо передавать в друг. дочерний и т.п. Я уже писал об этом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104922/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-bulson).