# Многопоточность в редакторе Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, tpl, unity3d-editor, unity3d-faq

Я хочу параллельно делать какие-то штуки в редакторе, но при этом я не хочу вешать UI редактора во время расчетов. Можно ли использовать Task'и или что-то подобное? Или хотя бы потоками вручную управлять?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно, за одним исключением - **Unity запрещает вызывать большую часть своего API вне своего главного потока**.

Класс Debug и его методы, к слову, могут вызываться в дочерних потоках.

Что в "рантайме", что в редакторе, Unity имеет свою реализацию SynchronizationContext - [UnitySynchronizationContext](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnitySynchronizationContext.cs), кроме этого, нам, в принципе, ничего и не нужно.

---

Тривиальная задача решается просто до безобразия:

```
CancellationTokenSource _cts;

var token = _cts.Token;
var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
Task.Run(() => DoWork(context, ...), token);
```

Это все и так было понятно, вопрос состоит в том, чтобы после этого вернуться в главный поток, да и к тому же еще в какое-то окно что-то передать.

Ну, вариантов у нас не особо много, а вернее ровно 1 - `EditorWindow.GetWindow<T>`, который либо создает окно, либо восстанавливает сохраненное окно, либо же, в лучшем случае, фокусируется на открытом окне.

Для бэкграунд таска хотелось бы, чтобы окно что-то там обновляло, но пользователя не дергало и не забирало фокус у активных окон. Тут у нас уже 2 выхода:

1. Singleton - классика, но к нему уже банально не интересно обращаться за решением :)
2. `GetWindow<T>("Title", focus: false)` - придется передавать заново заголовок окна, но что поделать.

Остановимся на втором варианте и получим что-то такое:

```
private static CustomWindow GetCustomWindow(bool focus) {
    return GetWindow<CustomWindow>("Task example", focus);
}
```

---

Дальше все тривиально:

В своем окне имеем какую-то меру "прогресса":

```
private float _progress = 0f;
private float Progress {
    set {
        _progress = value;
        // этот вызов перерисовки обязателен - без него не обновится визуал
        Repaint();
    }
}
```

Делаем важные вещи в таске - спим:

```
private static void DumbTaskExample(int subTaskCount, int sleepTime, SynchronizationContext context, CancellationToken token) {
    Debug.Log($"Task started at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    for (int i = 0; i < subTaskCount; i++) {
        // Cancellation
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        
        // Work
        Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
        
        // Notification
        context.Post(_ => GetCustomWindow(false).Progress = (float)i/subTaskCount, null);
    }
    Debug.Log($"Task done at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    context.Post(_ =>  GetCustomWindow(true).OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled(), null);
}
```

`Debug.Log()` просто ради логов - так проще отлаживать. С помощью контекста получаем ссылку на окно и вызываем у него нужные методы.

Таинственный метод в конце таска - освобождение ресурсов и флагов:

```
private void OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled() {
    _taskRunning = false;
    _cts.Dispose();
    _cts = null;
}
```

---

Чего-то примечательного в вызове таких тасков или их отмене нет:

```
private void OnGUI() {
    ProgressBar();
    if (_taskRunning) {
        if (GUILayout.Button("Cancel task")) {
            _cts.Cancel();
            OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled();
        }
    }
    else {
        _sleepTaskCount = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Sleeping tasks count:", _sleepTaskCount);
        _sleepTaskTime = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Sleeping time (ms):", _sleepTaskTime);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Start single task") && _sleepTaskCount > 0) {
            _progress = 0f;
            _taskRunning = true;
            
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = _cts.Token;
            var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            Task.Run(() => DumbTaskExample(_sleepTaskCount, _sleepTaskTime, context, token), token);
        }
    
    }
}


private void ProgressBar() {
    var size = position.size;
    var fullRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(size.x, 30);
    var completedRect = new Rect(fullRect.x, fullRect.y, fullRect.width * _progress, fullRect.height);
    
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(fullRect, Color.black);
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(completedRect, Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, _progress));
    
    EditorGUI.LabelField(fullRect, $"{_progress * 100}%", EditorStyles.centeredGreyMiniLabel);
}
```

Получаем результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также не стоит забывать про цепочки тасков. Например, если нужно выполнить несколько последовательных задач, но при этом результат каждой задачи зависит от предыдущей и нужно бы проверить достоверность результатов на всех этапах. Ну или какой-то этап мог спокойно прокинуть исключение.

Пишем хэндлер исключений:

```
private static void HandleTaskException(Task task) {
    Exception ex = task.Exception;
    while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Task chain terminated", $"Exception: {ex.Message}", "Ok");
}
```

Создаем цепочку:

```
Task.Run(() => DumbTaskExample(_sleepTaskCount, _sleepTaskTime, context, token), token)
    .ContinueWith(
        t => { HandleTaskException(t); OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled(); }, 
        token, 
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, 
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
    );
```

Здесь очень важно указывать планировщика текущего контекста, иначе продолжение выполнится там же, где и таск - вне главного потока Unity.

Из всего этого получаем не очень красивое, но зато блокирующее весь UI Unity диалоговое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Полный код

*код помещен в контейнер ради спойлера*

```js
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomWindow : EditorWindow {
    [MenuItem("Window/Task example")]
    private static void ShowWindow() {
        GetCustomWindow(true).Show();
    }
    
    private static CustomWindow GetCustomWindow(bool focus) {
        return GetWindow<CustomWindow>("Task example", focus);
    }
    
    private float _progress = 0f;
    private float Progress {
        set {
            _progress = value;
            Repaint();
        }
    }
    
    private bool _taskRunning;

    private int _sleepTaskCount = 3;
    private int _sleepTaskTime = 1000;

    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    private void OnGUI() {
        ProgressBar();
        if (_taskRunning) {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Cancel task")) {
                _cts.Cancel();
                OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled();
            }
        }
        else {
            _sleepTaskCount = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Sleeping sub-tasks count:", _sleepTaskCount);
            _sleepTaskTime = EditorGUILayout.IntField("sleeping time (ms):", _sleepTaskTime);
            if (GUILayout.Button("Start single task") && _sleepTaskCount > 0) {
                _progress = 0f;
                _taskRunning = true;
                
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = _cts.Token;
                var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                Task.Run(() => DumbTaskExample(_sleepTaskCount, _sleepTaskTime, context, token), token);
            }
            else if (GUILayout.Button("Start chained task") && _sleepTaskCount > 0) {
                _progress = 0f;
                _taskRunning = true;
                
                _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = _cts.Token;
                var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
                Task.Run(() => DumbTaskExample(_sleepTaskCount, _sleepTaskTime, context, token), token)
                    .ContinueWith(
                        t => { HandleTaskException(t); OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled(); }, 
                        token, 
                        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, 
                        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
                    );
            }
        }
    }

    private void ProgressBar() {
        var size = position.size;
        var fullRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(size.x, 30);
        var completedRect = new Rect(fullRect.x, fullRect.y, fullRect.width * _progress, fullRect.height);
        
        EditorGUI.DrawRect(fullRect, Color.black);
        EditorGUI.DrawRect(completedRect, Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, _progress));
        
        EditorGUI.LabelField(fullRect, $"{_progress * 100}%", EditorStyles.centeredGreyMiniLabel);
    }
    
    private void OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled() {
        _taskRunning = false;
        _cts.Dispose();
        _cts = null;
    }

    private static void DumbTaskExample(int subTaskCount, int sleepTime, SynchronizationContext context, CancellationToken token) {
        Debug.Log($"Task started at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        for (int i = 0; i < subTaskCount; i++) {
            // Cancellation
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            
            // Work
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            
            // Notification
            context.Post(_ => GetCustomWindow(false).Progress = (float)i/subTaskCount, null);
        }
        Debug.Log($"Task done at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        context.Post(_ =>  GetCustomWindow(true).OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled(), null);
    }

    private static void HandleTaskException(Task task) {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            Exception ex = task.Exception;
            while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Task chain terminated", $"Exception: {ex.Message}", "Ok");
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Итог

Мы получили довольно простой в написании способ создавать таски и даже цепочки тасков с обработкой исключений. Сюда еще можно прицепить токены отмены, обработку этих ситуаций, обрабатывать ситуации закрытия окна, etc.

Ответ и без всяких тонкостей получился громоздкий, да и на основе этого можно уже всякие примочки сверху приделать - было бы желание :)

Comment: Не иначе как в ответ на проблемы у @Ivan Triumphov.

Comment: @Bulson он самый, но решил оформить в виде обособленного от конкретной задачи вопроса, чтобы потом можно было людей сюда отсылать.

Comment: Пока просто запустил не вникая .... у меня прогресс бар всегда на нуле , почему то )

Comment: Unity 2018.4.1f1 (64-bit) дома

Comment: @IvanTriumphov кнопка `Start single task` вызывает метод, который бросает исключение, что было сделано для примера, оттого и на нуле. Я исправил код, теперь исключения нет.

Comment: большое спасибо ))) очень благодарен ....я уже сам тоже догадался почему так .... вы как всегда очень полезно и основательно даёте ответ

Comment: @IvanTriumphov пытаюсь восполнить пробелы в публичном хранилище знаний, сам нередко спотыкаюсь об отсутствие банальной информации о чем-то в юнити, а иногда и об проблемы, о решении которых никто никогда не писал. Так что делюсь своим опытом, как могу :)

Comment: Если мне надо выполнить метод в дочернем потоке и подождать пока он выполниться. Как мне это сделать ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov зачем запускать метод в отдельном потоке и виснуть главный, дожидаясь его? Проще сразу запустить метод в главном потоке и все.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  Мне надо выполнить AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (tempTex2D) в дочернем потоке , для того чтоб отрисовать объект. Для меня не имеет смысл иначе код. Вообще там метод который выполняется в дочернем потоке , вызывает в районе 5 таких методов

Comment: @IvanTriumphov во-первых вы опять хотите вызывать API юнити вне главного потока, во-вторых вы хотите синхронно вызвать асинхронный код. Я просто не совсем понимаю, в чем смысл создавать таск на отдельном потоке и при этом блокировать основной поток, дожидаясь, пока выполнится таск.

Comment: я делаю string path = await Task.Run (() => AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (tempTex2D)); в цикле метода DumbTaskExample . и программа перестаёт , отрабатывать дальше

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Мне надо сделать метод который отрисовывал бы объекты , при этом , когда Unity отрисовывает объекты , надо повесить прогресс бар. Методы которые отрисовывают объект используют API юнити

Comment: Вы меня не слышите, **нельзя** вызывать API юнити в тасках или других потоках. Метод дальше идет, потому что ` AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath` в другом потоке выкинет исключение про то, что нельзя вызывать его в другом потоке, поскольку обработки исключения в таске нет, он просто отваливается и ничего не происходит. В ответе есть пример, как обработать исключения в таске на уровне основного потока.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105077/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб вызвать  API юнити в тасках беру [Dispatcher](http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/the-dispatcher-pattern/) или [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1060765/178835) и переделываю метод так DumbTaskExample :

```
async private static void DumbTaskExample (int subTaskCount, int sleepTime, SynchronizationContext context, CancellationToken token) {
    Debug.Log ($"Task started at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    for (int i = 0; i < subTaskCount; i++) {
        // Cancellation
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested ();

        // Work
        Thread.Sleep (sleepTime);
        string path = "none";
        Debug.Log ("path=" + path);
        path = await Task.Run (() => {
            bool val = false;
            Dispatcher.Instance.Invoke (() => {
                Texture2D tempTex2D = Resources.Load<Texture2D> ("Texture/Rock (Moss)");
                path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath (tempTex2D);
                Debug.Log ("Dispatcher.path=" + path);
                val = true;
            });
            while (val == false) {
                Debug.Log ("val");
            }
            return path;
        });
        Debug.Log ("path=" + path);

        // Notification
        context.Post (_ => GetCustomWindow (false).Progress = (float) i / subTaskCount, null);

        //throw new Exception("Dumb exception");
    }
    Debug.Log ($"Task done at {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    context.Post (_ => GetCustomWindow (true).OnTaskFinishedOrCanceled (), null);
}
```

не забудьте добавить в OnGUI():

```
 private void OnGUI() {
  ...
  Dispatcher.Instance.InvokePending ();
 }
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну что, разобрались или еще какие-то вопросы остались?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  у меня пока прогресс бар отвалился, но код стал быстрее работать с вашими изменениями... сейчас надо срочно к следующей пятнице показывать... по как другим занят .... позже вопросы появятся