# C# Моргание при многопоточном рисовании элементов в WinForms

Tags: c#, многопоточность, графика

существует следующая проблема, при рисовании элементов, в отличном от главного потоке вызывается событие

```
EvNeedToRedraw?.Invoke();
```

По следующему делегату

```
public delegate void NeedToRedraw();
```

Подписывается на событие

```
EvNeedToRedraw += Redraw;
```

И обновляется PictureBox

```
void Redraw()
{
    BattleField.Invalidate();
}
```

Если использовать

```
void Redraw()
{

    BattleField.Refresh();
}
```

То вылетает следующая ошибка:
*System.InvalidOperationException: "Недопустимая операция в нескольких потоках: попытка доступа к элементу управления 'BattleField' не из того потока, в котором он был создан."*

Но если использовать

```
void Redraw()
{
    BattleField.Invalidate();
}
```

То возникает моргание, из-за того, что PictureBox обновился, но объекты ещё не отрисовались, или были отрисованны до обновления, т.е. дважды были отрисованны на на одно обновление PictureBox

Код рисования:

```
 while (true)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.AntiqueWhite);
            lock (ListObj)
            {
                foreach (var i in ListObj)
                    i.Draw(IsNeedToDraw);

                for (int i = 0; i < ListObj.Count; i++)
                    if (ListObj[i].IsNeedToDestroy)
                    {
                        if (ListObj[i].GetType() == new PersonDrawTickImage().GetType())
                            ((PersonDrawTickImage)ListObj[i]).InvokeEventForAddToDrawList(EvNeedToAddStaticPicture);
                        ListObj.RemoveAt(i);
                    } 
            }
            Thread.Sleep(Pause);

            EvNeedToRedraw?.Invoke();

            if (Ticks == 1)
                IsNeedToDraw = false;
            else if(Ticks == MaxTicks)
            {
                Ticks = 0;
                IsNeedToDraw = true;
            }
            Ticks++;
```

Мне нет нужды отрисовывать несколько объектов каждый тик, для этого необходим счётчик прошедших тиков

Буду благодарен, если объясните где ошибка и как избежать моргания(моргают только объекты, на всех пк)

Comment: 1) обновлять виз.интерфейс нужно в контексте синхронизации см.[пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1087440/222542) 2) [Уменьшение эффекта дрожания изображения посредством двойной буферизации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls)

Comment: Благодарю, вероятно решение проблемы будет заключаться в SynchronizationContext